# My Macbook Pro will not detect my samsung galaxy s6

Tags: android, macos, usb

I'm trying to connect my samsung galaxy s6 to my macbook pro to run my apps from android studio; however, when I connect my phone to my mac via the usb cable that came with the phone, i get a notification on my phone that it is charging but my macbook and android studio do not detect it.

I have usb debugging on.
Kies and filetransfer don't work.

I cant see the directory in finder even though I have show external disks and hard disks checked.

My phone and mac are both running the latest versions of android and OSX.

Comment: You need to go to the samsung site and download the drivers for your model. Even if when you plug it in it "sets it up", it's probably not all the way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but when I plug it into my mac nothing happens. I mean literally nothing expect the charging sound from my phone. Also, I thought you didn't need the drivers for mac.

Comment: Well maybe not. Samsung doesn't seem to offer them directly.

Comment: Yeah , so what do I do? surely I cant be the first one to attempt this. I tried to use SmartSwitch but my mac just does not detect my phone at all.

Comment: This may be better suited for the [enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour) or [super users](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: I *just* got it working for me (latest generation MBP / El Capitan / VZW Galaxy S6). I had ruled out it being a cable issue after trying 3 different cables... but I found another one and gave it a try (weirdly, a OnePlus One cable), and it's working like a charm now. I'll mention that I did also install ADP somewhere along the way, but I don't believe that was part of the solution, as it still doesn't work on the previous 3 cables.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the cord provided by samsung is with mac computers due to OEM compatibility issues. Using a different cord with correct OEM data transfer compatibility will fix the issue.

Comment: Really? That's an absurd issue! Is it an issue that persists across all macs or just a certain lot. IOW; is it macs in general or is it more of an issue of old mac interfacing with new samsung hardware? Also, was your solution found on your own or from another source? You can accept your answer as "the one;" if you like; it may prove to be helpful to others.

Comment: I actually tried a different cable and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I solve it by using android file transfer. Download it from android official website https://www.android.com/filetransfer/

Install it on Macbook Pro and connect your phone with cable and ROCK!

Answer (score 0):

Try PdaNet, it can help you find your device's driver version and match with your device.

Comment: I tried it and fallowed all the instructions however it requires the computer to detect the presence of the phone it needs to connect to, which is the problem I am having

Comment: once you plugin your phone, do you have the charge logo on the top of your device?

Comment: yes, my phone charges but otherwise it doesn't connect with the computer

Comment: so that's not your hardware's problem. Can I have your email? I can send you my driver to see whether that work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this issue. I've got an s6 edge and a new macbook retina pro; so it's definitely not an issue of "old mac" to new samsung.

Edit: Fixed it by chatting with samsung.

From your phone dial *#0808# then check the MTP option to enabled. Hit reboot.
Also make sure to install smart switch on your computer, available at http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/smartswitch/

When the smartswitch window appears, hit the drop down menu, and then click the blue folder icon. That should do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post "me too" type comments as answers.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I did find a solution and I updated my answer to an actual answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with another USB cable and it worked. Its the problem with defult USB cable coming along with mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue with Samsung Note-8. My macbook pro was not detecting my phone. So, i just tried with another cable and it worked. there is no need to download samsun